# Can project SVN structure be easily changed?

Tags: svn

I recently joined a project where the SVN repo is structured as follows

```
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Files>
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but I would have expected it to have been setup as follows.

```
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Trunk>-<Files>
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Branches>-<Files>
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Tags>-<Files>
```

I am in the process of completing a CI process that generates weekly artifacts for each project, but having seen the repository structure I wonder what pain it will cause if I do the following and leave the current repo structure as is?

```
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Files> (Current trunk)
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Branches>-<Files>
<SVN root>-<Project Name>-<Tags>-<Files>
```

Will this cause a problem or is this perfectly acceptable?

Comment: How do you plan to take a new branch? You'll need to copy everything from project-name without the branches and tags subdirectories, and I don't think you can do that in one go on the command line like you can for just copying a whole folder. Ditto if you want to merge between branches and trunk. It may be simpler just to insert a trunk folder or equivalent and go through a one-time change in everyone's working copies.

Comment: Ok.  I see what you are saying. So the current structure is not fit for purpose and a new one will have to be created and the old project code moved across?

Comment: I'm sure you can make it work, I just think it would be simpler to avoid putting the branching tree into the normal checkout folder. That may mean introducing a new layer, or if you wanted to avoid that you could put the branches folder elsewhere e.g. projectname_branches, projectname_tags? I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks.  Have decided to accept the pain and modify SVN structure so that it is correct, otherwise, I just envisage a world of pain later on.